Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost Worldchain
I am trying to send Worldcoins via the Worldchain mainnet. I have 4.94 WLD available in my Worldcoin address, but when I call the function to transfer, I get the following error:
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (transaction="0x02....", info={ "error": { "code": -32000, "message": "insufficient funds for gas * price + value: balance 0, tx cost 256698173634, overshot 256698173634" } }, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=6.13.4)
at makeError (ethers.js?v=cb8393ce:325:15)
at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (ethers.js?v=cb8393ce:19051:16)
at ethers.js?v=cb8393ce:19215:27 overrideMethod @ hook.js:608 transfer @ WorldChain.ts:101 await in transfer transfer @ Dashboard.tsx:57
(anonymous) @ Dashboard.tsx:67
commitHookEffectListMount @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:16915
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:18156
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:18129
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:18119
commitPassiveMountEffects @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:18109
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:19490
flushPassiveEffects @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:19447
(anonymous) @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:19328
workLoop @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:197
flushWork @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:176
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-RPCDYKBN.js?v=cb8393ce:384
Show 12 more frames
Show less

This is the code responsible for attempting to send the Worldcoins:
async transfer(address: string, amount: string) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/v1/get-private-key-and-public-key", {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`
            },
            withCredentials: true
        });

        if (response.data.status === 'success') {
            const privateKey = response.data.private_key;
            const RPC_URL = "https://worldchain-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/TOKEY_API";
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x2cFc85d8E48F8EAB294be644d9E25C3030863003";
            const ABI_TRANSFER = [
                "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
                "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
                "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)"
            ];

            const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
            
            const wldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI_TRANSFER, wallet);
            const balance = await wldContract.balanceOf("WALLET");                
            const decimals = await wldContract.decimals();

            const ethBalance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
            console.log("balance of ETH in wei:", ethBalance.toString());
            const formattedBalance1 = ethers.formatUnits(ethBalance, "ether");
            console.log("Formatted ETH balance:", formattedBalance1);

            const formattedBalance = ethers.formatUnits(balance, decimals).replace('.', ',');

            console.log(`Current Worldcoin balance: ${formattedBalance} WLD`);

            const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amount, decimals); 

            const gasEstimate = await provider.estimateGas({
                to: address,
                data: wldContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [address, amountInWei]),
              });
              console.log("Gas estimate: ", gasEstimate.toString());


            const tx = await wldContract.transfer(address, amountInWei, {
                gasLimit: gasEstimate,
            });
            console.log(`Transaction sent: ${tx.hash}`);

            await tx.wait();
            console.log(`Transaction received: ${tx.hash}`);
            
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

Console Javascript response:
Balance of ETH in wei: 0 WorldChain.ts:76
Formatted ETH balance: 0.0 WorldChain.ts:80
Current Worldcoin balance: 4,994 WLD WorldChain.ts:88
Gas estimate:  21786

I have ETH available, but it only shows up in the console if I call the ETH RPC instead of the WorldCoin RPC. I researched this, and they said I needed to have ETH, so that's what I did.
Image of Worldscan

Network address of my wallet (in case you want to check it on your own):
0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776

Please translate your question into English.

Done, it's already translated into English.

Your WLD tokens are on the world chain, but the ETH you are talking about is on the Ethereum chain.
They are two different blockchains.
To make transactions on the World Chain you need to have ETH on World Chain, not Ethereum.
Here's the docs for funding your wallet in World Chain

I understand. Is it possible to pay the ETH gas (Worldchain) with another wallet and then transfer the tokens? If so, what modifications should I make in the code or what should I look into?
